# Why use a functor when you can use a function reference

Tags: c++, function-pointers, functor

Eg suppose you want to do the factory pattern. Why do this:

```
class IFooFactory {
public:
 virtual ~IFooFactory() {}
 virtual std::unique_ptr<IFoo> operator()(int bar, int baz) const = 0;
};

class AFactory : public IFooFactory {
public:
 virtual std::unique_ptr<IFoo> operator()(int bar, int baz) const override {
  std::unique_ptr<IFoo> a(new A(bar, baz));
  return a;
 }
};

class BFactory : public IFooFactory {
public:
 virtual std::unique_ptr<IFoo> operator()(int bar, int baz) const override {
  std::unique_ptr<IFoo> b(new B(bar, baz));
  return b;
 }
};

void doStuff() {
 std::unique_ptr<IFooFactory> fooFactory(new BFactory);
 doMoreStuff(fooFactory);
}
```

When you can just do this:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<IFoo> (&FooFactory)(int bar, int baz);

std::unique_ptr<IFoo> AFactory(int bar, int baz) {
 std::unique_ptr<IFoo> a(new A(bar, baz));
 return a;
}

std::unique_ptr<IFoo> BFactory(int bar, int baz) {
 std::unique_ptr<IFoo> b(new B(bar, baz));
 return b;
}

void doStuff() {
 doMoreStuff(BFactory);
}
```

What are the advantages of the first solution? It just looks like convoluted OO crap to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example neither `AFactory` nor `BFactory` use local state. For example creating `B`s may need additional parameters provided to the factory's constructor and the second solution will have problems with that:

```
class BFactory : public IFooFactory {
  int zoo;
public:
  BFactory(int zoo): zoo(zoo) {}
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IFoo> operator()(int bar, int baz) const override {
    std::unique_ptr<IFoo> b(new B(bar, baz, zoo));
    return b;
  }
};
```

If you know you won't need local state in the factory, then going for the simpler format is better.

Comment: So if local state is not required, then the second one is better?

Comment: I think so. It depends on how certain you are that it will not be needed in the future and some estimate of what would be the cost to change it later if you happen to be wrong. For example if the interface will be exposed by some library for others to use, it might be better to have the more general interface. On the other hand you should generally keep yourself from over-engineering things. Quite often the seemingly more general interface still manages to be inadequate later in development due to changes in requirements you did not anticipate.

Answer (score 1):

Using a functor mean you'll call a **method** on an **object** (an actual instance of some class), rather than calling a simple function, which has no context. It means the result of the call may be determined by the state of the object.

The same could be done with a method pointer, but then you'll have to pass the method pointer **and** the object on which to call the method.

Using a functor, you only need to pass the object, which is usually much more readable.

Comment: So if context is not required, then the second one is better?

Comment: @grasevski It's not better, it's just different... You may assume you'll never need a context, of course... But since you're using an object-oriented language, using methods on objects is usually encouraged, as it should make your code more modular.

Comment: @grasevski Don't think about the amount of code needed for a single purpose. Try to think about the modularity of your code, and about the things you may need in the future.

Comment: I'm not convinced that an object is objectively more "modular" than a function. It makes little sense to think of what I "may need in the future". Should I make a factory for my factory? Should I wrap this factory factory in an interface, just in case I need to sub in another factory factory? I'm also not convinced that C++ is strictly object oriented.

Comment: note also that the first solution is much more convoluted and bug-prone